# Why is output not driven through interface clocking block?

Tags: interface, verilog, system-verilog

In the example below, I am trying to pulse the `data` output on `my_interface`. However, `data` always remains 0.

```
interface my_interface(
  input  clock,
  output data);

  clocking cb @(posedge clock);
    output data;
  endclocking
endinterface // my_interface

module test;

  logic clock;
  wire  data;

  my_interface my_interface(.*);

  initial begin
    clock = 0;
    #1 $display("%0d data:%0d", $time, data);
    #10;
    my_interface.cb.data <= 1;
    #1 $display("%0d data:%0d", $time, data);
    @(my_interface.cb);
    my_interface.cb.data <= 0;
    #1 $display("%0d data:%0d", $time, data);
    #20 $display("%0d data:%0d", $time, data);
    $finish();
  end

  always #5 clock = ~clock;

endmodule
```

The sim output is:

```
# 1 data:z
# 12 data:z
# 16 data:0
# 36 data:0
```

I'd like to understand why is `data` never `1` in the example above?
I can fix the issue by replacing `#10` with `@(my_interface.cb);`, but I don't know why this fix works.

Code and results on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very dangerous to use any other blocking events other than @(my_interface.cb) when driving or sampling clocking block signals The reason your code is behaving that way is because of this statement in section 14.16 Synchronous drives:

> It is possible for a drive statement to execute at a time that is not
>   coincident with its clocking event. Such drive statements shall
>   execute without blocking, but shall perform their drive action as if
>   they had executed at the time of the next clocking event.

In your example, your two drive statements wind up driving in the same cycle, and last write wins.

So the rule is only to use @(my_interface.cb) to block a process that is driving or sampling clocking block signals. That includes not using wait(cb.signal) and instead using @(cb iff (cb.signal))

Comment: I'd recommend specifying the LRM version as section can vary. In this case it looks like IEEE std 1800-2012 or 1800-2009.